# Check whether a char is a letter or a number?

Tags: rust

What are the Rust equivalents to C's `isalpha`, `isdigit` and `isalnum`?

Comment: Those C functions are locale dependent, while Rust is fixed to Unicode chars.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`is_alphabetic, is_digit, is_alphanumeric, is_numeric` are what you are looking for.

e.g. :

```
fn main() {
    println!("1 is a digit {}", '1'.is_digit(10));
    println!("f is a hex digit {}", 'f'.is_digit(16));
    println!("a is alphabetic {}", 'a'.is_alphabetic());
    println!("こis alphabetic {}", 'こ'.is_alphabetic());
    println!("a is alphanumeric {}", 'a'.is_alphanumeric());
    println!("1 is alphanumeric {}", '1'.is_alphanumeric());
}
```

returns:

```
1 is a digit true
f is a hex digit true
a is alphabetic true
こis alphabetic true
a is alphanumeric true
1 is alphanumeric true
```

They are described in detail in the [Rust standard library docs for chars](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html).